# Error message - conflicting int/float/boolean and use of String

Tags: string

I am fairly new to processing - I have a coursework deadline on Monday (6th January).

I am trying to write a script that randomly generates shapes and numbers and draws these shapes. I am getting an error message in relation to the use of the String function and if function.

It seems that the if function requires a boolean number but the string function cannot produce a boolean. Please could you advise a way around this?

**PROCESSING CODE**

float shape;

int number1;

int number2;

void setup()

{

size(600,1000);

background(255);

stroke(0);

strokeWeight(3);

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)

{

```
String[]words = {"circle", "square", "line"};

int shape = int(random(4));

println(words[shape]);


for(int b=0; b<2; b++)

{

  int number1 = int(random(8));

  println(number1);

}
```

}

}

void draw()

{

if(shape="circle")

{

ellipse(number1, number1, 50, 50);

color(32,78,95);

noStroke();

}

if(shape="square")

{

rect(number1, number1, 50, 50);

color(255,198,168);

noStroke();

}

else

{

line(width/2, 600, number1, number1);

stroke(183,215,216);

}

}

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question to be moved to stack overflow.

However, this will help, change

```
if(shape="square")
```

to

```
if (strcmp(words[shape], "square") == 0)
```

However, it's even better not to compare to strings at all, what you should do is create an `enum` type of shapes (with values Circle, Square etc), and for the random value (which is an integer), use the `switch` statement and compare to 0, 1, 2, ... or better e.g. int(Circle), int(Square).